# Google closure on CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, google-closure, google-closure-library

My goog dependencies are working 100% on a regular server, but I'm moving to CouchDB, which as you might know, sort of destroys the file hierarchy. Some of my dependencies aren't loading, but I am not sure why. Does anyone know of a good way of finding out where it *thinks* the dependency files are, which ones its successfully getting versus not...

Basically, what's the best way to debug this? Or is there a way in CouchDB to make it so I don't have to change the locations of the files.

EDIT: It seems to be working about 50% of the time (it should show some musical notation.) In FF it seems to work more often. Thoughts?

http://fullscore.iriscouch.com/fullscore/_design/API%20Tests/public%2fpublic%2fscore-library%2ftests%2f01a-Pitches-Pitches.html